# How to get spoken instructions from Google Maps while bicycling?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-navigation

I run Google Maps 9.57.1 on Marshmallow.

When I use directions in the "bicycle mode" I don't get any spoken directions. I only get this "ding" sound, without any audible indication as to where I'm supposed to go. This is a major inconvenience, as it's often very difficult to stop in the middle of traffic (losing all my speed, etc.) to take out the phone and look at the display.

When Maps is in "car" mode, spoken instructions work just fine.

Is this by design? Why is Maps like this? How can I get spoken instructions while bicycling?

FWIW, my phone is set to English language. I have had this problem in several countries, but I'm mostly based in Norway.

I'm open to using root access and Xposed Framework to fix this, should that be required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of these solutions may help, assuming muting Volume is not the cause

- [Download Voice Directions](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3273406?hl=en&visit_id=1-636371830178091506-3687881973&rd=1) by keeping map open and getting directions

> Sometimes voice directions aren’t downloaded or need to be updated on your phone or tablet. When this happens, you’ll hear a chime instead of voice directions.

- Solution for same problem from [Maps help](https://support.google.com/maps/forum/AAAAQuUrST8F3WXbQ7bHT4?hl=en)

  1. Uninstall and reinstall Maps updates
  2. Ditto for play services
  3. Clear Cache of maps before navigation